# YouCompleteMe vim plugin with clangd completer appears to be not working

Tags: c++, vim, youcompleteme

Following the [official guide](https://github.com/ycm-core/YouCompleteMe/wiki/Full-Installation-Guide), I installed YouCompleteMe including semantic support with clangd completer. Did everything exactly as the guide says it (starting by cloning the project to .vim/bundle and the doing git submodule init).

For clangd flags, I found a `.ycm_extra_conf.py` in the directory ~/.vim/bundle/YouCompleteMe/third_party/ycmd/.ycm_extra_conf.py

My full .vimrc file looks like:

```
set number
syntax on
filetype plugin indent on
set tabstop=4
set shiftwidth=4
expandtab

" YouCompleteMe settings
let g:ycm_clangd_binary_path="/usr/bin/clangd"
let g:ycm_global_ycm_extra_conf="/home/me/.vim/bundle/YouCompleteMe/third_party/ycmd/.ycm_extra_conf.py"
set runtimepath+=~/.vim/bundle/YouCompleteMe/plugin/youcompleteme.vim
```

Then I created a test.cpp file in my home directory and tried typing in some code, but the YouCompleteMe autocomplete is not working. I'm not seeing any suggestions at all.

EDIT:
My clangd version is 9.0.1

EDIT 2:
Appended .vim file path of the plugin to .vimrc. Still not working.

Comment: Is YouCompleteMe even loaded?

Comment: @MateenUlhaq Removed the `:`. I have a feeling that YouCompleteMe is not loaded. Is there anything I need to do to load it?

Comment: The same as any other plugin. Depends on how you're installing the plugin. Are you using a plugin manager like `vim-plug`?

Comment: @MateenUlhaq No, I installed this manually using cmake.

Comment: Hmmm... I don't personally use YCM so I'm not sure. You might get better answers from https://vi.stackexchange.com (you can flag this question for a moderator to migrate) or from YCM's Issue Tracker.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I have flagged it for migration.

Answer (score 1):

So the problem was, I needed `set runtimepath+=~/.vim/bundle/YouCompleteMe/` instead of `set runtimepath+=~/.vim/bundle/YouCompleteMe/plugin/youcompleteme.vim` and this line needed to go before the line `filetype plugin indent on`.